# Expression trees vs IL.Emit for runtime code specialization

Tags: c#-4.0, code-generation, metaprogramming, specialization, partial-specialization

I recently learned that it is possible to generate C# code at runtime and I would like to put this feature to use. I have code that does some very basic geometric calculations like computing line-plane intersections and I think I could gain some performance benefits by generating specialized code for some of the methods because many of the calculations are performed for the same plane or the same line over and over again. By specializing the code that computes the intersections I think I should be able to gain some performance benefits.

The problem is that I'm not sure where to begin. From reading a few blog posts and browsing MSDN documentation I've come across two possible strategies for generating code at runtime: Expression trees and IL.Emit. Using expression trees seems much easier because there is no need to learn anything about OpCodes and various other MSIL related intricacies but I'm not sure if expression trees are as fast as manually generated MSIL. So are there any suggestions on which method I should go with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance of both is generally same, as expression trees internally are traversed and emitted as IL using the same underlying system functions that you would be using yourself. It is theoretically possible to emit a more efficient IL using low-level functions, but I doubt that there would be any practically important performance gain. That would depend on the task, but I have not come of any practical optimisation of emitted IL, compared to one emitted by expression trees.

I highly suggest getting the tool called [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) that reverse-compiles CLR assemblies. With that you can look at the code actually traversing the expression trees and actually emitting IL.

Finally, a caveat. I have used expression trees in a language parser, where function calls are bound to grammar rules that are compiled from a file at runtime. Compiled is a key here. For many problems I came across, when what you want to achieve is known at compile time, then you would not gain much performance by runtime code generation. Some CLR JIT optimizations might be also unavailable to dynamic code. This is only an opinion from my practice, and your domain would be different, but if performance is critical, I would rather look at native code, highly optimized libraries. Some of the work I have done would be snail slow if not using LAPACK/MKL. But that is only a piece of the advice not asked for, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: I would add that writing your own IL is fraught with opportunities to miss optimizations that the C# compiler might find.  You may want to emit actual C#, and use the C# compiler to generate your resultant assemblies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx

Comment: @ChrisShain, unfortunately, C# compiler does not do any of the interesting possible optimisations. Even C++/CLI is doing much more for some reason. That's why I prefer to generate the code on my own, bypassing the C# limited optimisation capabilities. There are things which are very easy to implement but missing in C# - a proper constant propagation, constant arguments specialisation (with inlining), region analysis and allocation elimination, loop unrolling, variables coalescing, loop invariant hoisting, etc.

Comment: The reason the C# compiler doesn't do these optimizations, is that this responsibility is in the JIT compiler. The reasoning here is that by moving optimizations like loop unrolling to the JIT compiler, they are applied to all .NET languages. Of course, the JIT compiler does do loop unrolling, inlining and a lot more.

Comment: You guys might want to see [is-il-generated-by-expression-trees-optimized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355297/is-il-generated-by-expression-trees-optimized).

Answer (score 2):

If I were in your situation, I would try alternatives from high level to low level, in increasing "needed time & effort" and decreasing reusability order, and I would stop as soon as the performance is good enough for the time being, i.e.:

- first, I'd check to see if Math.NET, LAPACK or some similar numeric library already has similar functionality, or I can adapt/extend the code to my needs;
- second, I'd try Expression Trees;
- third, I'd check [Roslyn Project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/10/19/the-roslyn-preview-is-now-available.aspx) (even though it is in prerelease version);
- fourth, I'd think about writing common routines with unsafe C code;
- [fifth, I'd think about quitting and starting a new career in a different profession :) ],
- and only if none of these work out, would I be so hopeless to try emitting IL at run time.

But perhaps I'm biased against low level approaches; your expertise, experience and point of view might be different.

Comment: Emitting il is a major pain in the ### but you learn alot about how inner workings of clr!!!